# Cayley Graph of a Group Action

Tags: group-theory, cayley-graphs

Suppose $F_2 = \mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z} $ and $ \Gamma_S$ be the Cayley Graph of $F_2$ over the usual generating set.

So we have a usual 4-regular tree as $ \Gamma_S $

Suppose $ \mathbb{Z} $ act on $ \Gamma_S $ by left action. How does the quotient graph $ \mathbb{Z} / \Gamma_S $ look like?

Comment: It is a circle with infinite trees planted at it's vertices.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? How do we get this?